# Open a VFP Database Container with OpenData event coded

Tags: vba, excel, visual-foxpro

I am migrating data from a Visual FoxPro Data Base Container to Excel using VBA.

After trying and failing various settings of the Connection String in order to open the Container, I discovered that at Container was placed code at OpenData event; this code asks a password to open the Container. This prevents other programs open the Container for access to data, including the Password parameter of the Connection String.

Are there a way to open the Data Base Container with OpenData coded event? If the answer can be implemented in VBA, please let me know how I can do it.

Thanks for your attention.

PD: Forgive my english. Is not so good.

Answer (score 2):

Solution details would probably depend on what the (custom) "Stored Procedure" code in the Vfp database is doing exactly, where one way could be simply removing it. If you got a Visual FoxPro IDE, you could for example do so by using the IDE's "Command Window":

```
MODIFY DATABASE ?
```

and then right-click the Database Designer window, choose the desired "Event" in the Properties dialog -> "Edit Code".

If then for example the code would simplified look like

```
PROCEDURE dbc_BeforeOpenTable(cTableName)
*Just before a table or view is opened. Return .F. to prevent table or view being opened.

    RETURN INPUTBOX("Password") == "Test"

ENDPROC
```

... you could simply

```
RETURN .T.
```

instead